# Page size option in IE11's Page Setup only shows Oficio 216x340mm, Oficio 8.5x13 and Youkei 3 (98 x 148mm) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, network-printers, page-setup

We have this intermittent printing issues with network printer where we triggered Page Setup in IE11 in the Win7 PC, it does not give us the usual Page Size like A4, A5, A6. Instead we are only allowed to choose from Oficio and Youkei. Restarting the PC usually resolves this issue temporarily but it will happen again.

Any IE settings/configs that we should change to fix this?

[image: Page Setup]

Comment: Please try to check whether this issue only occurs in the IE 11 browser or you can also produce the same issue while printing with any other application on your machine? Try to install the latest updates for your Windows 7 OS to check whether it helps to fix this issue or not. Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.